# Modify a list element in function of the other elements in the list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of elements of type LocalType (defined below),

```hs
data Direction = Send | Receive
               deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Read)

data LocalType = Act Direction String LocalType
                 | End    
               deriving (Eq, Ord, Read)
```

My goal is that every (Send string) in the list gets removed if a (Receive string) is present in another element of the same list. The (Receive string) will also be removed. (and vice-versa)

This list looks like this for example,

```hs
let list = [(Act Send a End), (Act Receive a End), (Act Send b End)]
-- [!a;end,?a;end,!b;end]
```

The output list should be,

```hs
[(End), (End), (Act Send b End)]
-- [end, end,!b;end]
```

How could these be implemented in the haskell function below ? Could be done using foldr() ?

```hs
rule :: [LocalType] -> [LocalType]
prefixRule list = do 
    -- implementation
    list
```

Comment: What I would do is loop through the whole list, keeping track of what got sent and what got received, then loop through again and remove the ones that got both.

Answer (score 0):

Since the correct answer for any member of the list can depend on a value in any position in the list, whether before or after it, this problem cannot be solved with a single traversal, and therefore using a single fold is not the best approach.

I think @Aplet123's comment is the right direction. I have come up with the following solution, which gives the correct result on the eample case. I have used standard combinators instead of explicit folds, so if you're new to Haskell, it may be worth spending some time trying to unpack what's going on here.

```hs
import Data.Set hiding (map)
import Data.Maybe

data Direction = Send | Receive
               deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Read)

data LocalType = Act Direction String LocalType
                 | End
               deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Read)

list :: [LocalType]
list = [Act Send "a" End, Act Receive "a" End, Act Send "b" End]

rule :: [LocalType] -> [LocalType]
rule lts = process (toSet lts) lts

toSet :: [LocalType] -> Set (String, Direction)
toSet = fromList . mapMaybe go
  where
    go End = Nothing
    go (Act d s t) = Just (s, d)

invert :: Direction -> Direction
invert Send = Receive
invert Receive = Send

process :: Set (String, Direction) -> [LocalType] -> [LocalType]
process s = map process'
  where
    process' End = End
    process' lt@(Act dir str _)
      | member (str, invert dir) s = End
      | otherwise = lt
```

Happy Haskelling!